# How to test my Android application on my Sony Xperia M4 Aqua device and why the ADB driver is not available?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, sony, sony-xperia

**Hello everybody,**

I try to use my new Sony Xperia M4 Aqua Dual to test an android application on Android Studio.

**But I need the ADB driver for M4 and it is not available in the drivers download page : [Sony drivers](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/)**

The fastboot driver doesn't work too.

Someone has the same problem, but still nobody has answered :
[ADB Interface driver for Sony Xperia M4 Aqua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891117/adb-interface-driver-for-sony-xperia-m4-aqua)

Someone may have encountered the same problem ?

**Thank you very much by advance,
Boris**

Comment: This is not the appropriate place to ask for phone drivers. As suggested in the comment for the question you linked to, you may try http://android.stackexchange.com/  (note that the question you're asking has already been asked there, so you shouldn't post a duplicate question)

Comment: Not solved on Windows, but worked on Linux after adding correct access right

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the sony companion app, that did the trick for me to get my drivers updated. But I had another Xperia phone than yours.